# Payment provider requiring frontend only?

Tags: paypal, payment, frontend

Most of the payment providers (Stripe, Braintree, Samurai etc) is requiring a backend implementation.

My website is using static HTML served from a CDN and has no backend since I am using Kinvey (Backend as a service).

I wonder if there are payment providers that only require frontend implementation (JS/HTML) so I can keep on going without a backend since payment is the only feature missing from my website.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, PayPal Website Payments Standard is ideally suited for that. It requires only a simple  to be added to your site.

For example;
`<form method="POST" action="http://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"> 
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">

<input type="hidden" name="business" value="you@yourdomain.com">

<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Your item name">

<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="0.99">

<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Continue to PayPal">

</form>`

Of course, you'll need to keep in mind that even though the amount is in a 'hidden' input field, it's still open to manipulation.
Instead, you could use also log in to your PayPal account and go to the '[button factory](https://www.paypal.com/buttonfactory)' and create a so called 'hosted button'.
Here the amount is fixed and stored on PayPal's side, so that it can't be manipulated.
The downside, is that it's a fixed amount and you'll need to make an API call if you wish to automatically update it.

Comment: Wow, didn't know about that. Is PayPal the only one providing frontend-only implementation?

Comment: BTW. I forgot to tell you that one criteria is to make it possible to pay with just a credit card without having to create an account at the Payment Provider (PayPal). I guess PayPal is ruled out?

Comment: Sure, PayPal does that as well, depending on the country you're in. If you're in the US or Europe you most certainly can. Just tick the 'PayPal Account Optional' setting in your 'Selling Preferences' on your PayPal account.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind: someone who *hasn't* logged in on www.paypal.com previously, will then see the 'Billing' landing page the first time around. Whereas someone who *has* logged in before (such as you) will be shown the 'Login' panel immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a similar thing with [Google checkout shopping cart](https://checkout.google.com/seller/integrate_shoppingcart.html).

I found it extremely easy and hassle free to integrate into my page served from a static server, and was initially impressed with how simple and quick it was to get a page that could take payments up.

On the other hand, I've lost a lot of sales because people say that they are not prepared to 'create a google account' just to pay me.  I will be ripping it out and replacing it with another within the next few months.  Probably the PayPal one as that's the only other one that I know of that works without a server and the payment process is more lightweight and a better experience for the users, although it's a shame that it doesn't seem to provide shopping cart like facilities, unlike the google one.

Also, initially the google guys messed up the forms and didn't fix it for months, despite pleas from me pointing to the exact problem. So you can't rely on them to fix things for you quickly, even if you're losing sales from it.

Comment: I just came across http://simplecartjs.org/ which looks like it does what I need.